# Replace text before other scripts load

Tags: javascript

I have piece of code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="custom.js?token={{token}}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

`main.js` is my script which replace in `body` tag `{{token}}` for value provided from Query.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var link_sid = query.get('link_sid');
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/{{token}}/g, util.protocol() + '://c.' + util.env() + util.domain() + '/' + link_sid);
}
```

`custom.js?token={{token}}` is user content which I can't change.

The problem is that user JS put some HTML code based on my `{{token}}` value.
So after open page all `{{token}}` are changed but not inside custom JS cos token was changed after JS was loaded.

How can I replace `{{token}}` in custom.js query before it loads? It needs to be done in pure JS.

**[Updated 1]**

I can't move anything from `body` also can't change. Body is user-provided content.

Comment: At the time the second script can be modified by JS it is already executed, I think you should remove it from HTML and add it dynamically

Comment: I cant. All content in `body` is user-provided and I wrap it around with rest html

Comment: cant you replace in server side?

Comment: then keep it and add a new script tag, the one present will result in a silent unhandled `404 not found`

Comment: You can look into `DOMContentLoad` event, and put the call to load JS at the end of HTML file

Comment: Why dont you use an MVC framework like Angular and then dynamically replace the h-ref. If you are interested I can post you the solution

Comment: @vizsatiz no. i cant. this code will be injected on iframe.

Comment: Injected from where? At some point, you must have it as a string before you do wrap it in your own html. That's when you should do the replacing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your script dynamically. Here is one way to do it by creating script tag and appending it to the page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>
        var script = document.createElement("script")
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "custom.js?token=" + "your_token"
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    </script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't move anything from body to head as the body is user-provided content.

Comment: @Pyton Changing the src of already loaded script tag will do nothing because of security issues. You can modify the source server side before sending the HTML to the browser. There you can set the token in similar fashion as you already tried to do with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I can see the way you are passing `{{token}}` to `custom.js` is a hacky way. I can suggest you to change the way it should be like this:

1. Since `main.js` is your script, you can try to assign the `{{token}}` to a global value, example:

Inside `main.js`:

```
    window.TOKEN = util.protocol() + '://c.' + util.env() + util.domain() + '/' + link_sid`;
```

2. In the html will still be the same, except you don't need to add the `{{token}}` string:
3. Then inside `custom.js`, you can use `window.TOKEN` to do whatever you want with it.

If the `window.TOKEN` is evaluated asynchronously, you will also need a callback function from `main.js` to tell `custom.js` when the token is ready, then it can start using it, example:

**When TOKEN have to be asynchronous:**

In `main.js`:

```
    var TOKEN = util.protocol() + '://c.' + util.env() + util.domain() + '/' + link_sid`;
    typeof window.tokenReady === 'function' && window.tokenReady(token); // make sure it's a function before calling it
```

In `custom.js`:

```
    window.tokenReady = function (token) {
      // Do something with token
    }
```